# How can I close the browser window after redirecting to an MS office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) document automatically opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery-events

In the web application I am working on, we have some long-running processes that are in charge of getting office documents. We basically open a popup with `window.open` which takes care of polling the server to report the process status and to wait for the availability of the document, and redirect to the generated document when it is ready (window.location = THE_URL_OF_THE_FILE).

When the redirection happens, depending on the user configuration (see Microsoft Knowledge base), the MS office document may be opened/embedded directly in Internet Explorer, or it may open the file in a new instance of office suit.

In the latter case, the document opens successfully in Excel, but the window that caused its opening stays there forever.

Is there a way to force that window to close as soon as Excel has successfully loaded the file ?

I expect this is somehow related to how the integration between IE and Windows works ...

**EDIT**

```
$.ajax({
           async: false,
           type: 'Post',
           dataType: 'json',
           url: '/Controller/Action/' + docId,
           data: $('form').serialize(),
           success: function (url) {
               window.open(url, 'ShowFile', 'top=25,left=50,width=680,height=400,help=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,toolbars=1,menubar=1,resizable=1',false);
       }
   });
```

The document is opened in a new word instance and then the window remains open after the document is opened, but the window should close when the file is opened in a new Ms office instance.
Url is location on the server pointing to the document.

Comment: You cannot close browser windows/tabs via JS unless that window was opened by JS.

Comment: im using a js command (window.open) to open the new window which will have a link to word document and it opens the file

Comment: As epascarello said - it can't be done. There is **no way** to check if the document was opened by some plugin in the browser or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. For many reasons:

1. After you change the `window`'s location, you cannot execute any code - you're done
2. The document opened in a new window cannot communicate with the old window, because it is not an HTML page and you cannot execute any JavaScript there
3. There is no way of telling how the document will be handled. You can do some guess work depending on the browser type and OS being used, but that will always be a guess. It could either be downloaded, opened in some plugin, opened natively in [Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) (upcoming feature), opened automatically in MS Word... the possible outcomes are endless.

I suggest you rethink your website logic.

I would suggest performing some [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) instead of opening a new window and use that to check the status of the document, and when it's ready, open it in a new window.

If you really need to open a new window to do that, I suggest you change the `document.location` of your *parent* window (the one you've used to open the pop up). After that close the pop up. This will not redirect the page to a new location but open the document as you've described (however that behaviour cannot be guaranteed depending on the user's setup).

Comment: Just for notice: 1 and 2 can be solved with a frame. So only 3 is a real unsolvable problem.

Comment: "(...)the MS office document may be opened/embedded directly in Internet Explorer, **or it may open the file in a new instance of office suit**. In the **latter** case, the document opens successfully in Excel, **but the window that caused its opening stays there forever**." - this is his problem.

Comment: As about frames: instead of redirecting to `file.pdf` you redirect to `viewer.page?file=file.pdf`. That viewer page contains some javascript code you require and a `<iframe>` which has it's `src` changed to the real `file.pdf`. When it's done, the main page (parent of iframe) is still in your command, and Javascript can still be run there. However, that still does not solve the 3-rd part, you don't know if the iframe is rendering the document, or if the Save/Open dialog was shown.

Comment: @Max: Again, that is not the problem he's having. He's not talking about document that are embedded within the browser, he's talking about the documents opened in the Office Suite.

Comment: I believe it's the same as with viewing PDFs in embedded viewer. There is no magic behind office suit, it uses some plugin for IE which shows documents embedded into the placeholder page. Anyway, if you put the document path in the frame instead of window location - you will have control over the remaining page without losing any of the functionality of embedded viewer. That's why 1 and 2 are not a problem if you put it into frame.

Comment: @Max: Please read the question carefully, then read the parts I've bolded out. Also, for reference, his main question: _"Is there a way to force that window to close as soon as Excel has successfully loaded the file?"_ He's talking about the actual Office Suite, the actual software running on his machine, not the plugin. Get it now?

Comment: I actually got the question from the start. Now I'm not getting what you are trying to prove. I'm stating that your point `After you change the window's location, you cannot execute any code - you're done` is wrong in authors case. You can put the file URL into a **frame** and get **absolutely same result** without losing your javascript code.

Comment: @Max: You're wrong, when you do `document.location = something`, you cannot execute any code in the same page. There is no point continuing this discussion.

Comment: @Max: I keep explaining to you, you've done that IN A FRAME, you haven't redirected the user on the same page!

Comment: exactly my point. And the frame is fullscreen, therefore from user point of view - he sees no difference. That's the way it is usually done, and it had been working for years in all of the browsers in all of my projects that used it. Even embedded documents work well. And that's exactly why your points 1 and 2 can be fixed with frames.

Comment: @Max: You did not get what I was trying to say in point 1 and 2. The problem cannot be fixed with frames - you have no idea when the document has actually loaded, therefore you cannot close the window after that (you can wait an ambiguous number of seconds and then close the window, but you have no guarantee that the document has loaded).

Answer (score -1):

Following is the code snippet for window open/close using Javascript (source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp). You can probably modify it for your needs:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function closeWin()
{
myWindow.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWin()">
<input type="button" value="Close 'myWindow'" onclick="closeWin()">

</body>
</html>
```

You can use jQuery and implement sort of call-back on window.open. Also, if the window is opened from another window by javascript, then there is a parent property; it can be used to communicate between two windows.

Comment: And how exactly will you know that you need to close your window in the case of the author?

Comment: @Max I imagine after some delay once the opened window communicates with the parent window and tells it to close it. But this solution is not ideal.

Comment: Please reread the question. Author is opening a window with a **file** in it. The file is either opened with some plugin (like pdf viewer in IE) or Open/Save dialog is presented. How will you understand which one of those was it? In one case you close the window, in other - window contains the document and should not be closed.

Comment: He probably can implement some sort of callback; I don't have the exact solution at this time. Also, if the window opens another window by javascript, then there is a parent property; can be used to communicate between two windows. On a separate note: why do you down-vote me and what's wrong w/w3school?

Comment: I am asking again: why did you down-vote my answer? It's for the author to decide if it's helpful or not.

Comment: 1. That was the question of the author. He asked specifically on how to close the window **when it is no longer needed**. You failed to provide and answer to the `when it is no longer needed` part. 2. I down-voted you for what I explained in (1). This is not an answer to the question of an author. If he asked 'How do I close window with javascript' - it would be. 3. Read the link you obviously ignored (was in first comment by MMM): http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @AlexBell No, it's for the community to decide if it's helpful or not. The OP only accepts your answer.

Comment: Thanks For the suggestions but i m still figuring a way to find the solution.... @Max && MMM you are right!!.. the windows opens a file type of tiff , jpeg and pdf embeded in IE but not office suit

Comment: Well, it's kinda disappointing :( It means that some self-appointed so-called "community" (actually it seems like two of you working in concert) are to decide what is good for the author, and what is not. Also, why should I trust that site you have mentioned more than w3schools? It's a bit unclear. Anyway, I don't want to get involved in that kind of "web politics"... let's move on. Rgds, AB

Comment: Also, as a warning: stop down-voting my other answers or I will report your unethical actions to the site administration. Cyber-bullying will not be tolerated on this site!

Comment: Back to the technical side: it's clearly stated that the image/pdf files are opened in IE (or whatever is a default browser on that particular machine). It's exactly what I was expecting. It means that the second window contains "implicit pointer" to the first one, which is 'parent' property. And that one can be closed on timer event as pointed out in the comments thread. The solution, indeed, is not ideal, but still might be useful. Rgds, AB